# Not able to insert update delete

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I'm using Asp.net c# and MYSql as back-end. I'm updating a table,but table is not updating.There are only 3 columns in the table.

There is no *exception* when I'm executing the command object. But this returns 0 value from `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

I debugged this and found cmd.Parameters are full with values. and if i manually run the update command in mysql it works fine.

the table is as follow

```
column -- Datatype   
ShortText -- varchar   
title -- varchar   
id -- int
```

Please guide me...

```
int retVal = 0;
        string shortText = ((TextBox)fmvwShortText.FindControl("txtShortText")).Text.Trim();
        try
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(((Label)fmvwShortText.FindControl("lblShrtTextID")).Text);
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["conn"]);
            cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE temp_posts SET ShortText=@shrtText WHERE id=@id AND Title=@title";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@shrtText", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = shortText;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@title", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value =Session["EditTitle"].ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = id;
            con.Open();
            retVal = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
        return retVal;
```

Comment: Does it throws any exception? Write *debug* statement and set break point inside the catch block.

Comment: Adding commantype= storedproceudure  must help

Comment: include "throw;" within exception quotes and see the exception.

Comment: Do you need second condition in WHERE? Id should be enough.

Comment: @satindersingh Command Type is Query and not a Stored Procedure. However CommandType is needed: CommandType.Text

Comment: @Code1008:  yeah i meant same commandType.text is needed

Comment: @AVD no doesn't throw any exception.

Comment: Remove the `try..catch` block and see what happen?

Comment: @ Code1008, satinder singh i have checked using CommandType.Text. Still it is not performing.

Comment: @ManishKumarNamdev You need to let us know the exact Exception.

Comment: @Code1008 dear friend, I have used try and catch blocks in my code no exception is halting the program. this runs but doesn't update the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thank you every one who kept looking and tried their best to sort out this problem with me..

Finally got the solution.

In my code I used **@ in cmd.CommandText and in parameters.**
But when I replace this **@** with **?** both in cmd.CommandText and in parameters and used the **cmd.ExecuteScalar();** this worked.

**Actually Parameter names depend on the provider. When using the provider for
SQL Server, it should start with @ (e.g. @param1). For Oracle
provider, it should start with a colon (...for e.g. aram1. For
OleDb provider, just a question mark (?) would work**

Thank you everyone to contribute your best... many thanks

But i'm still left with a question that ExecuteScalar() is updating the records in the database? I am with no answer... looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possibly a casing issue with your `Title` parameter? I notice you are only updating if the ID & Title match *exactly*?

Also as a general rule of thumb, when using objects which implement `IDisposable` you should wrap them with a `using` statement, this will make sure your objects are always disposed (even on the result of an error)

```
using (var con = new MySqlConnection(...))
{
    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(...))
    {
       ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this nt sure about code formating coz currently am not using ide frmwrk

```
int retVal = 0;
        string shortText = ((TextBox)fmvwShortText.FindControl("txtShortText")).Text.Trim();
        try
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(((Label)fmvwShortText.FindControl("lblShrtTextID")).Text);
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["conn"]);
            cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE temp_posts SET ShortText='"+shortText+"' WHERE id='"+id+"' AND Title='"+Session["EditTitle"].ToString()+"'",con);
            con.Open();
            retVal = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        return retVal;              
    }
        catch (Exception e) { }
```

Comment: -1 For recommending raw SQL over SQL parameters. Your asking for trouble writing SQL statements like this this leaves you wide open for SQL Injection.